# emailjs smtp server connection fails

Tags: javascript, smtp

I have a code section like this,

```
let email = require('emailjs/email');
let server= email.server.connect({user:'someone', password:'pw',host: 'mail.acompany.com', 
tls: true,port:25,timeout:30000});
let txt='this is a test';
server.send({  text: txt, from: 'iamfrom', to:'iamto',cc: '', subject: 'test'}, function(err, message) { console.log(err || message); });
```

The code section is executed on windows 7's nodejs env. The versions are

[image]

But the final result is

[image]

It looks like that the line2 execution is erronous, but I cannot figure out a good reason, especially when this code works fine in another environment (ubuntu+emailjs1.0.x).

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enabled the debug flag inside emailjs in client.js

```
...
this.smtp.debug(1);
....
```

I found the connect works fine, but it cannot send anyway.
And the ping works OK. Thanks for Costa's reminding.

Finally, I use smtpjs instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute in command line:

```
ping mail.acompany.com
```

If it something like this

```
5 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

then the environment cant reach the server